# React Native - Using lockstate to track lock/unlock events

Tags: react-native, locking, unlock

I want to track **lock** and **unlock** events in React Native, to be able to measure time spent on screen and the number of times people unlock their phones. I am trying to use lockstate (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-lockstate) but I am pretty new to RN and I'm not quite sure if this should be connected to AppState also or the best way to handle it.

My component code is the following:

```
export default class LockStateCheck extends Component {

  state = {
    lockState: RNLockState.currentState
  }

  _handleAppStateChange = (thisLockState) => {
    if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && thisLockState === 'active') {
      console.log('App has come to the foreground!')
    };
    this.setState({lockState: thisLockState});
  }

  handleLockStateChange = (thisLockState) => {
    if (this.state.lockState(.match(/lockcomplete/)) && thisLockState === 'unlocked')
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    RNLockState.addEventListener('change', this.handleLockStateChange);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    RNLockState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleLockStateChange);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Text></Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I have not, had to go for a different approach in concept unfortunately.